# OpenGL-ES 2.0 Problems Implementing Fade Out in Shader

Tags: opengl-es, shader, gradient

I'm plotting some lines and want them to fade out.  I'm new to shader coding and I'm not sure what my problem is.  I'm passing a vector array for the line and a transformation matrix, as well as a uniform color and a starting point for the fade.  I'm using a varying to pass the position on the line from the vertex shader to the fragment shader.  The code says that the fragment shader is not compiling.

**Vertex Shader**

```
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
varying vec4 pointLocation;

void main() { 
    gl_Position = matrix * position;
    pointLocation = gl_Position;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 uniformColor;
uniform vec1 fadeStart;
varying vec4 pointLocation;

void main() {
   lowp vec1 distance;
   lowp vec4 color;

   color = uniformColor;
   distance = pointLocation.x - fadeStart;

   if (distance < 30) {
        color.w = distance / 30;
   }

   gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: What, specifically are the compiler errors?

Comment: The 30 should have been 30.0 - see the comments on @vasaka's reponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no vec1 it is just float. Also you can get compiler errors with OpenGL that would give you a clue what syntax errors you have.

Comment: how can i get the opengl compile errors?  I'm doing this through monotouch for ios.

Comment: @reza using glGetShaderInfoLog usage samples are easy to find

Comment: the code I'm using does get the logs, but they appear to be empty.  It first checks the logLength, and if >0 then it does a GetProframInfoLog -- but nothing is output from this.  -- I also changed var1 to float but no go.  I'm trying a number of small iterative changes to see what breaks it.

Comment: i found a bug in the opengl libs I was using.  They call GetProgramInfoLog rather than GetShaderInfoLog.  WIN!  this is the error.. Fragment Log: ERROR: 0:14: '<' does not operate on 'float' and 'int' -- I can use this to debug. thanks!